# How to implement a list of fallback functions

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a list of functions returning `Option[Int]` and I want to return the result of the first one returning `Some(…)`, and not compute the rest of the functions after it. For example:

```
val list = List(
  () => { println("a"); None },
  () => { println("b"); Some(1) },
  () => { println("c"); Some(2) },
  () => { println("d"); None }
)
```

In this case, the result will be `Some(1)`, and it will print only `a` and `b` (since the rest is not computed).

My solution was

```
list.foldLeft(Option.empty[Int]) { (a, b) => a orElse b() }
```

The question if there's a more elegant/concise way of doing it, or maybe some library?

Comment: To be more concise, `list.foldLeft(Option.empty[Int])(_ orElse _())`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
list.view.flatMap(_()).headOption
```

`a` and `b` are only called once. `c` and `d` are never invoked or even iterated over. Returns `None` if there are no `Some()` values.

The `.view` wouldn't be needed if `list` was type `LazyList`.